# Applying a CSS style to all HTML tags with Stylus

Tags: html, css, stylus

I would like to use Stylus to hide all images. I have a very small script that I put together which works nicely for img elements but I am battling to make it also apply to background images. It looks like I have to make a special case for each type.

For example, there is still an image displaying on the old buildapcsales reddit page (https://old.reddit.com/r/buildapcsales/) after enabling this script. That is happening because the `background-image` is only being applied to the `div`'s and the `body::before` elements because those are the only ones that I specified in the script. I would like to apply this `background-image` style to all HTML elements on the page.

The Stylus script I have so far looks like this.

```
img {
    display:none !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
  }

div {
    background-image: none !important;
}

body::before {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

This works on most pages. With the page that I linked (and other pages) it doesn't apply to all HTML elements. The `img` portion is applied to all of the HTML `img` elements but the `background-image` is only applied to the specified elements. While hiding the `section` one (which is the problem on this page), I am looking for a a generic way that I can hide all background images or apply my style changes to all HTML elements/classes? I tried various options using * to apply the change to all children but that didn't help. For example this does nothing.

```
* {
    background-image: none !important;
}

* > * {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

I don't want to target specific classes by name.

Comment: Please provide enough information *in the question it self*. Don't make us go off site and guess what exactly you are referring to in around 150 lines of often minified HTML. A [mcve] in your question would be beneficial.

Comment: @JonP You don't even need to look at the external page. I don't want to get something working with a specific page because that would mean that the same would have to happen for other pages. I would like to apply a CSS style to all HTML elements on a page in Stylus. In this case, I want to apply the `background-image: none !important` style to all HTML elements on the page. So the question is how can I apply a style to all HTML elements on a page? I have updated the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the backgrounds may be specified with the shorthand `background` property.

```
* {
  background-image: none !important;
  background: none !important;
}
```

Since CSS selectors are prioritized by *specificity*, by definition you can't apply a generic selector.

Comment: I tested that. It doesn't help. It also has the side effect of removing all background elements and not just the images.